# Propagating higher order Hermite Gaussian modes. What are complex amplitude coefficients?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, fourier-transform

I've been tasked with writing a code (in MatLab, but I'm currently using Mathematica because I don't know MatLab %\ ...) to simulate the propagation of a Gaussian beam.
I don't really know anything about optics, so I'm learning on the fly using [this manual](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2973) kindly provided to me by my adviser.
I'm stuck trying to figure out what the general closed form of a complex amplitude coefficient a[j,n,m] (p.74 and also below) would look like :( Could someone explain it please?

---

[image]

---

i have looked through various articles and presentations such as
http://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys4510/phys4510_fa05/Chapter5.pdf (and others i can't post links too because of my low reputation) and haven't seen mention of said complex amplitude parameter anywhere else. Lots of complex amplitudes, but not parameters. I don't think they are the same thing, are they?

Comment: We don't debug code here, that can be done at either [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) or [scicomp.se]. Also, it's useful to ask a question when posting on a question & answer site.

Comment: I'm not asking to debug code ... i posted it to show that I'm working on something ... and I did ask a question ... I asked what the general closed form of the complex amplitude coefficient a mentioned in the manual is ... did you even read what I wrote?..

Comment: I did read it, and the text parser that is my brain sees a single question mark that is a request to "dumb down" some mathematics. The thing that you call a question seems to be a *statement* saying that you're stuck on something and not a question in any meaningful manner.

Comment: It is better, there's an actual question now. Note though that your PDF link is broken (leads to the image).

Comment: I think Hermite orthagonality can be used to Fourier transform as described here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Orthogonality but I'm not sure. Could someone confirm? It looks like it'll be horrible this way thought because of the argument of H and the extra k/2R term in the exponential...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that due to orthogonality relations of Hermite-Gauss poly's, Hermite-Gauss modes are orthonormal, so 
$$
\int \int u_{n,m} \left(u_{n',m'}\right){}^*dxdy=\delta _{m,m'} \delta _{n,n'}
$$

Then a's can be found by multiplying both sides by conjugate of u and integrating ...